# Single data context, many concurrent requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Entity framework allows only a single operation to be done concurrently (and I don't want to change that). Hence I must handle concurrent operations requested in one way or another. What is the standard way to handle this type of thing? Is there an already built in middleware? Also it might be nice if this middleware handles count of requests for given period of time ( e.g block requests when count of requests > 5 requests in the last 30 sec))

edit: The numbers are just an example.

Comment: "What is the standard way to handle this type of thing" - I highly doubt there's some to be a standard way of doing something so unique to your application. And painful for the users. Why did you tag this as ef-core-2.0? And your title mentions a "single data context" but your question doesn't go into any detail what you mean by that.

Comment: @mason looks like quite the standard thing one might do to avoid ddos attacks, simple - data contexts don't allow multiple concurrent requests executed on them. "so unique"

Comment: So create more data contexts? And no, I can't think of any website out there that only allows you to do only one request at a time.

Comment: you can't do that as you would be essentially editing the data while another thread is already editing it.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to come up with a transaction strategy.

Comment: @mason and you have arrived at my question, instead of downvoting it you could tell me - yep you're doing it wrong - you should do it that way #justathought

Answer (score 0):

I may not be fully understanding, but I’ll take a shot here.

It sounds like you’re trying to handle a number of similar requests concurrently, without necessarily modifying the same entity. If that’s the case, dependency injection mah be what you’re looking for. You can inject your context into the controller that handles the request and it can ensure that you receive a new instance of contexts for each request, for example. That may be what you’re looking for.

If you’re looking to handle a number of concurrent operations on a given entity without tearing your hair out, something like the actor model and Akka .NET might suit you. The actor model is a whole bunch to go into here, but one of the concepts is that it uses a mailbox and processes messages in the order they come in. So if you have one given entity, you can put that into an actor and it will handle one message at a tine for you, in order, making concurrency much easier to wrap your head around. It’s a great piece of tech.